# how to upload image to firebase storage from assets under folder. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to upload an image from my assets folder into my firebase storage under a folder with the user id as the folder name. but is the first time on my life using firebase storage so I have no idea how to do that. I saw people only upload those images as "File" variable from the image picker, but I have no clew how to convert the image to File variable. Thank you.

I found that line of code:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(uid).child("profile-pic.png").putFile(/*what am i puting here?*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the files from the **assets** folder, then you must use the **rootBundle**, as in:

```dart
var fileName = "assets/demo.txt";
ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(fileName); //load sound from assets
Uint8List rawData = bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes);
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('$fileName').putData(rawData);
```

Try that.

Comment: this code is let the user pic an image from his images. that not what I ment I want the code to do, I want to upload an image that is in my assets (in my project folder).

Comment: and it's not upload the image under a folder with a name I pick.

Comment: Check my updated answer using the **rootBundle** then.